# C++ Define an order for a set inside a class

Tags: c++, class, struct, set

I have a set inside a class, and I'd like to define a new order for that set, but the order depends on an attribute of the class. How should I implement it?
I tried something like this

```
class myclass{
    int c;
    set<int,cmp> myset;
    struct cmp{
        bool operator()(const unsint a, const unsint b)
        const {
            return (depends on c) ;
            }
    };
}
```

but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: The problem is that i don't know c a priori. It's a value i get in input, and then it will be always the same.

Comment: Do you have an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `return (depends on c) ;`

I think it's not good idea to make comapare function depend on `c`, because your `set` object is already built tree and no rebuild is supported by `std::set`.

Additionally, note that `std::set` requires Comparator which meet *strict weak ordering rule*.

You could read more at ['Compare' documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)

As for your problem, you could create another set with another compare function, and then copy contents here.

```
typedef std::set<int, cmp2> anotherSet;
std::copy(std::begin(firstSet), std::end(firstSet), std::inserter(anotherSet));
```

However, it looks like you actually don't need `std::set` if you have to reorder it depending on some parameter. Consider using another data structure like vector or list. Additionally, if you need ~O(log N) access complexity, you can organize data to [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) within your vector.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! What if I didn't know the value of c a priori? Can i create the struct cmp after i get the value (while it's running)?